# 0 rows when merging data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Basically every time I try to merge the two data frame I get back a merged data.frame with 0 rows.

The two data frames have different number of rows (one 122 the other 112), different numbers of columns and are are similar to these (data are all invented ndr):
df1

```
S_ID    BMI     WEIGHT  HEIGHT
AA1    18.0   50.0    178
BB2    20.0   60.0    173
CC3    16.0   47.0    170
DD4    23.0   75.0    170
```

df2

```
S_ID  sex  age   
AA1    F   20     
BB2    M   27   
CC3    M   26   
DD4    F   18
```

As you can imagine, I want to merge them by `S_ID`. I'm not interested in keeping the rows that are not present in both dataframes.
I tried:

- `merge(df1, df2)`
- `merge(df1, df2, by = S_ID)`
- `merge(df1, df2, by = S_ID, all=FALSE)`
  and even:
  `merge(df1,df2, by = S_ID, all=TRUE)`
  I use RStudio and I directly load the dataset from "import data". The dataset are originally both `.csv`.
  When I ask `typeof()` the two dataset, it says they are list.

**UPDATE:
Hi everyone, there was precisely an entry issue.
In df2 all the names in the column "S_ID" had blank spaces afterwards that I was not aware of.
Thank you very much for your help.**

Comment: Perhaps trailing or leading spaces in one of the S_ID columns?

Comment: `merge(df1, df2, by = "S_ID")` should work - note you need to quote the column names - not doing so would result in an error unless you had an object called `S_ID` in your environment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply; What do you mean by trailing?

Comment: I tried "merge(df1, df2, by = "S_ID")" it does not work

Comment: You should add a sample of your dataframes.  Use `dput(head(df1))` and  `dput(head(df2))` and paste the output in to your question.

Comment: sorry but I really can't.

Comment: You can obscure any sensitive information but you need to provide a sample where the issue is reproduced if you want further help.  Otherwise it's pure guesswork.  I would pay attention to @42-'s suggestion and make sure whitespace has been removed from both id variables.

Comment: Show the output of `str(df1); str(df2)`

Comment: Hi thank you all for the reply and sorry for being too vague. I don't know how to obscure the sensitive data and I'd rather get a bad review here than messing with private info because of my inexperience.
But thank you all for the replies, seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there is an obscure data entry issue. The line `merge(df1, df2)` should have been able to deliver a result .... UNLESS there is either a problem with one of those columns that prevents matching the "S_ID" columns, or there is a subtle difference in the naming of the columns. So to investigate this you would first try:

```
 "S_ID" %in% names(df1)
 "S_ID" %in% names(df2)
```

If the same name is in both then check the intersection of values in the S_ID columns (using `as.character` to avoid any difficulties with factor encoding)

```
intersect(as.character(df1$S_ID), as.character(df2$S_ID))
```

The `merge` function *should* be able to identify column names that are identical and then match rows on the character values of those rows.

Comment: I have the same issue but not yet resolved. I have checked the equivalence of names, it says TRUE for me. Next I checked the intersection it returns character(0). Can you explain what does it mean with respect to merge ( )

Comment: Without code the statement "checked the equivalence of names, it says TRUE" means almost nothing to me. `character(0)` is an empty vector. It means there are no exact matches. You should consider looking at `nchar` and `str` for better description of the parts you think should match. The `print` output you see on you console is often ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask what code you are using to read the data into RStudio? It sounds like you might be loading it in incorrectly.
Try:

```
df1 <- read.csv("YourFilepath")
df2 <- read.csv("YourFilepath2")

MergedData <- merge(df1,df2, by="S_ID")
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a data type issue though. If `class(df1)` returns "list", then merge and join functions won't know how to treat the variable. Try coercing your data type like the following:

```
as.data.frame(df1)
as.data.frame(df2)
merge(df1,df2, by = "S_ID")
```

Comment: class(df1) returns "dataframe"

Comment: @Tim : typeof(df1) should return "list" if df1 is a dataframe. No coercion should be necessary.